# Can I submit a paper to two or more journals at the same time?

Tags: journals, paper-submission

Assume I am submitting my paper to Journal X, which rejected the paper. After making modifications I am going to submit the paper to Journal X again. At the same time can I also submit the paper to another Journal Y (which has a lower impact factor than Journal X). As the Journal X has rejected it the first time, I think it may be rejected again. So I want to publish my work anyhow in a journal.

Comment: No, don't do that. I did not and I was not aware that I have to submit the same paper to different journals! The editor of the journal punished me by blocking me for submitting in one year as far as I remember, it was a harsh lesson as I wasn't aware of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No.

You must not submit to more than one journal at a time. Most journals explicitly forbid this in their policies. The reason is that people agree to spend a significant amount of time reviewing your paper essentially as a favour and their effort is completely wasted if you then say, "Thanks but my paper was accepted somewhere else."

You must decide now whether to resubmit to the same journal or to try for a less prestigious one.  Since you're asking the question, I assume you're a student: discuss this with your advisor!  That's what they're there for.

Answer (score 12):

No, not the same paper in two journals at the same time.

Either submit to X again or submit to Y.

Comment: But that means I have to wait again for 3 months for X's answer. What if the paper is accepted either in X or Y. After that can I withdraw the paper from other journal?

Comment: Yes, that is what it means. Journals frown on dual submissions. Most forbid it explicitly.

Comment: To add a rationale to this correct answer: the reason why journals don't allow parallel submissions is that it eats up resources with uncertain payoff. In particular, several reviewers will volunteer their work to review your submission. This could hardly be feasible, especially for less than top-notch journals, if there was a non-negilible risk that the submission could be withdrawn on a whim, e.g. because the author found a more prestigious venue or because another journal had a faster turnaround. If you attempt to do this, you risk being blacklisted.

Comment: For example, for American Physical Society journals, the Editorial Policies include the line that the corresponding author certifies: "The manuscript has not been published and is not being and will not be considered by another journal while it is considered here."

Comment: Thanks for the answers.